# How to solve a matrix equation for a scalar?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, matrix-equations, numerical-optimization

Given matrices $Q, P \succeq 0$, a vector $q$, a real number $\gamma$.
How can one solve the equation

$ q^T (Q+\lambda P)^{-T}P(Q+\lambda P)^{-1} q = \gamma$

for the scalar $\lambda$ in an efficient way.

As far as I know we need iterative algorithm for that. A quick look in the literature suggests that the so called safeguarded newton method can be used. I did not understand how it exactly works, but it seems that we need to find a Cholesky factor of $(Q+\lambda P)$ every iteration. This is quite expensive in terms of computations if the size of the matrices is large.

---

EDIT: 
One can also consider the simpler case when $P = I$ the identity and $Q$ is a diagonal matrix with the ith diagonal entry $Q_{ii}$, then the problem boils down to solving the following equation for $\lambda$

$\frac{q_1^2}{(\lambda+Q_{11})^2} + \frac{q_2^2}{(\lambda+Q_{22})^2} + \dots + \frac{q_n^2} {(\lambda+Q_{nn})^2} = \gamma$

Comment: What is the definition of $(Q + \lambda P)^{-T}$?  Is it $((Q + \lambda P)^{-1})^T$?

Comment: Yes. I used $(\cdot)^{-T}$ to denote the transpose of the inverse

Comment: OK, thanks.  Thinking . . .

Comment: If Q and P are PSD, why do you even need the transpose? Aren't they symmetric?

Answer (score 2):

### Algebraic fundamentals

If the matrix $A$ has characteristic polynomial $c(x)=c_0+c_1x+...c_nx^n$ then by Cayley-Hamilton, $c(A)=c_0I+c_1A+...c_nA^n=0$.

Divide $c(x)$ by $(1+λx)$, $λ^nc(x)=(1+λx)q(λ,x)+r(λ)$ where $q$ is a polynomial in $x$ and $λ$. Its coefficients in $x$ can be computed via the Horner-Ruffini scheme with arithmetic in the polynomial ring in $λ$. Again inserting $A$ for $x$ gives
$0=(I+λA)q(λ,A)+r(λ)I$ and thus
$$
(I+λA)^{-1}=-\frac{q(λ,A)}{r(λ)}
$$
Now assuming that $Q$ is invertible, set $A=Q^{-1}P$ to get the equation as a polynomial in $λ$ with fixed and reasonably easily computable coefficients.

---

For a related problem and inspiration, look up the Leverrier-Faddeev method and especially its derivation/proof.

---

### Algorithmic idea

Thus read your original expression as
$$
q^T(I+λPQ^{-1})^{−T}Q^{-T}PQ^{-1}(I+λPQ^{-1})^{−1}q=γ
$$
resulting in $A=PQ^{-1}$ or using a Cholesky decomposition $Q=CC^T$ the more symmetric expression
$$
q^TC^{-T}(I+λC^{-1}PC^{-T})^{−T}C^{-1}PC^{-T}(I+λPC^{-1}C^{-T})^{−1}C^{-1}q=γ
$$
with $A=PC^{-1}C^{-T}$.

In both cases, the expression to evaluate now has the form 
$$
v^T(I+λA)^{-1}B(I+λA)^{-1}v=γ.
$$
with $B=A$ in the second symmetric case.

Now compute $\chi_A(x)=\det(xI-A)=x^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+c_1x+c_0$ using your favorite algorithm, via Hessenberg form, Leverrier-Faddeev, Berkovitz,...

Perform polynomial division 
$$
λ^n\chi_A(x):(1+λx)
$$
with the polynomial ring in $λ$ as ground ring (for instance using multipoint evaluation--interpolation) to obtain $r(λ)$ and $q(λ,x)$, the latter as coefficient sequence for the powers in $x$ where the coefficients are polynomials in $λ$.

Using the vector sequence $v,Av,...,A^nv$ evaluate $q(λ,A)v$. Which now is a vector valued polynomial in $λ$.

And finally establish the polynomial equation
$$
(q(λ,A)v)^T·B·(q(λ,A)v)=r(λ)^2·γ
$$
which amounts to a convolution of vector sequences.

---

### Performance

One may now compare this procedure to the alternative of computing the eigenvector decomposition $A=UΣU^T$ in the second symmetric case resulting in the complete diagonalization 
$$
(U^{-1}v)^T(I+λΣ)^{-1}Σ(I+λΣ)^{-1}(U^{-1}v)=\sum_{k=1}^n\tilde{v}_k^2·\frac{σ_k}{(1+λσ_k)^2}=γ
$$
as proposed by Michael Grant. Essentially, this compares the most modern eigenvector decomposition, something like the implicit multi-shifted QR method, with the algorithm to determine the characteristic polynomial. The winner might depend on the required precision.

---

### More radical interpolation

With the knowledge that the original expression is rational in $λ$ and that the denominator is the square of a determinant, one can avoid almost all matrix decompositions except those to compute the matrix inverse resp. the solution of $(Q+λP)w=q$ for scalar values of $λ$.

Compute for a sequence $λ_1,λ_2,…,λ_{2n}$ of $2n$ (or more) distinct sample points (real or complex numbers) the values
$$
r_k=\det(Q+λ_k P),\quad s_k=r_k^2·q^T (Q+λ_k P)^{-T}P(Q+λ_k P)^{-1} q 
$$
Using one LU decomposition (or QR or...) $Q+λ_k P=LU$, both determinant and solution of the linear system $(Q+λ_kP)w=q$ can be obtained from the factors $L$ and $U$. (mantra: the $L$ in $A=LU$ and $A=LDL^T$ is the same for symmetric $A$.)

Using interpolation (if the $λ_k=q^{k-1}$, $q=e^{i\,2\pi/N}$, $k=1,...,N$, are equally spaced on the complex unit circle, this can be done via DFT or FFT) one obtains polynomial $R(λ)$ and $S(λ)$ in which the original equation reads as
$$
S(λ)=γ·R(λ)^2
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I followed what you are suggesting. what are $q(\lambda,x)$, and what is $r(\lambda)$. How do we get those?

Comment: What is the computational complexity of this approach, and how does it compare to the Cholesky approach cited by the OP?

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced you can escape the curse of $O(n^3)$ here. You are likely stuck with it. However, you can collect that work in pre-calculation, and get the Newton iterations down to $O(n)$.

I am assuming that $Q+\lambda P\succ 0$ for at least one $\lambda$, a reasonable assumption given that you're assuming $Q+\lambda P$ is at least sometimes invertible. Then $P$ and $Q$ can be simultaneously diagonalized; that is, there exists an invertible matrix $U$ such that
$$U^TQU = \Sigma_1, \quad U^TPU = \Sigma_1.$$
Determining the value of $U$ and its inverse will cost the equivalent of a few Choleskys.
$$ q^T (U^T(\Sigma_1+\lambda \Sigma_2)U)^{-1}U^T\Sigma_1U(U^T(\Sigma_1+\lambda \Sigma_2)U)^{-1} q = \gamma$$
This simplifies to
$$ q^T U^{-1} (\Sigma_1+\lambda \Sigma_2)^{-1}\Sigma_1(\Sigma_1+\lambda \Sigma_2)^{-1} U^{-T} q = \gamma$$
and then to
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{q}_i^2 \sigma_{1i} / ( \sigma_{1i} + \sigma_{2i} \lambda )^2=\gamma$$
where $\bar{q}=U^{-T}q$.
This doesn't get you away from some initial $O(n^3)$ calculations. But once you have done that, you can get the key iteration down to $O(n)$.

I will be honest, I am not sure this is necessarily better using a Cholesky in each iteration. The cost of the precalculation step is $O(n^3)$, but the $n^3$ coefficient is several times larger than the $1/3$ for a Cholesky.